# This htaccess file always appends new link to previous link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have uploaded my project from wamp server to godaddy hosting
now problem is when i click on any of my link it appends it to the previous url
please help
please check my website http://www.showbizwhisper.com

this is my navigation html

```
<li><a <?php if($page=="home") echo "class='active'" ?> href="home"><span><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="news") echo "class='active'" ?> href="news/1"><span>News</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="gossips") echo "class='active'" ?> href="gossips/1"><span>Whisper</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="movies") echo "class='active'" ?> href="movies/1"><span>Movies</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="dramas") echo "class='active'" ?> href="dramas/1"><span>Drama</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="celebs") echo "class='active'" ?> href="celebs/1"><span>Celebs</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="video") echo "class='active'" ?> href="video/1"><span>Music & Videos</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="gallery") echo "class='active'" ?> href="gallery/1"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="lifestyle") echo "class='active'" ?> href="lifestyle/1"><span>Life Style</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php if($page=="offbeat") echo "class='active'" ?> href="offbeat/1"><span>Off Beat</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue can be seen here:

`<li><a <?php if($page=="news") echo "class='active'" ?> href="news/1"><span>News</span></a></li>`

If you are on your website, on for example http://showbizwhisper.com/movies/1 and you click that link you will be taken to http://www.showbizwhisper.com/movies/**news/1**.

This is because your browser considers `1` the current file, and `news` the current directory, and your link states to go to a folder in the current directory, not the root directory.

To fix this, add a slash after `href="` so that the links now look like this:

`<li><a <?php if($page=="news") echo "class='active'" ?> href="/news/1"><span>News</span></a></li>`

This will make your link go to the root directory first.

You can also fix this by adding a base tag to your HTML document in the `<head>` section, like so:

`<base href="http://showbizwhisper.com" target="_self">`

Comment: can you guide I have lost all my image link too 
now is there a shortcut to avoid adding slash to every link in database

Comment: Yep, as I said just append `<base href="http://showbizwhisper.com" target="_self">` about your `</head>` tag. 

To explain:
The same issue applies to images, in your case `icon/twitter.png` will load `http://www.showbizwhisper.com/movies/news/icon/twitter.png` on `http://www.showbizwhisper.com/movies/1`

Adding the `<base>` tag is a quick fix to this.

Comment: The only solution i ever found! There's no other place at the WEB! Thanks @MarkHughes for answer and thank you Muhammad for asked!